# Send Html as text/html in Django

Tags: python, django, web

I have an `entry.html` file which looks like this:

```
{% extends 'encyclopedia/layout.html' $}

{% block title %}
    {{ title_name }}
{% endblock %}

{% block body %}
    {{ content }}
{% endblock %}
```

There are some markdown files (.md) which I have to read, convert to HTML, and display it on the webpage. There is a `util.py` file which returns the content of the markdown file by using the `util.get_entry(title)` function.

Here is my `views.py` file:

```
from django.shortcuts import render
from django.http import HttpResponse
from . import util
from markdown2 import markdown

...
def entry_page(request, title):
    md_text = util.get_entry(title)
    if md_text is not None:
        html = markdown(md_text)
        return render(request, 'encyclopedia/entry.html', {
            'title_name': title,
            'content': html
        })
    else:
        return HttpResponse('<h1>404 Page Not Found!</h1>')
```

The problem here is that the output is in plain text, like this:

[image: Error]

I want to send the text as html and not a plain text. How do I achieve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the [`safe`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/ref/templates/builtins/#safe) filter to disable HTML escaping for a template variable

```
{% extends 'encyclopedia/layout.html' $}

{% block title %}
    {{ title_name }}
{% endblock %}

{% block body %}
    {{ content|safe }}
{% endblock %}
```